upgrading Odoo 14.0 -> 17.0 Missing Field company_ids in res.partner
I am trying to upgrade our Odoo14.0 to 17.0 and just received the test upgraded database. We used some 3rd party modules, some OCA modules and a custom module inheriting report_layout.
When updating modules I always run in the following error:
2024-05-08 04:11:10,247 47514 WARNING odoo odoo.modules.loading: invalid custom view(s) for model res.partner: Fehler bei der Validierung der Ansicht nahe:

<form string="Partners" __validate__="1">
                <div class="alert alert-warning oe_edit_only" role="alert" name="warning_tax" invisible="not same_vat_partner_id">
                  A partner with the same <span><span class="o_vat_label">Tax ID</span></span> already exists (<field name="same_vat_partner_id" context="{'show_address': False, 'show_vat': False}"/>
                <field name="partner_gid" invisible="True"/>

Das Feld „company_ids“ existiert nicht im Modell „res.partner“ 

The field above, company_ids, does exist on res.partner and I cannot find the reason Odoo is exiting here.
Any suggestions?
I tried to update base but this also raises the error
